# jQuery Button Images Clickable

Tags: jquery, button

I'm using a jQuery code (source: http://jqueryui.com/button/#checkbox).

I wanted to add an image to the button after the text, however I can only check a category when I click the word and not the picture.

Is there anyway I can ammend the code so that the checkbox can be checked when clicking anywhere on the button?

Code below:

```
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title>jQuery UI Button - Checkboxes</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">   

      <style>
      #format { margin-top: 2em; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="format">
  <input type="checkbox" id="check1"><label for="check1">Option 1<br><img src="http://www.sustainweb.org/img/alert_small_star.png"></label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check2"><label for="check2">Option 2<br><img src="http://www.sustainweb.org/img/alert_small_star.png"></label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="check3"><label for="check3">Option 3<br><img src="http://www.sustainweb.org/img/alert_small_star.png"></label>
  <p id="text1">Hello</p>
  <p id="text2">Bye</p>
  <p id="text3">Other</p>
  <script>
  $(function() {
      $( "#check" ).button();
      $( "#format" ).buttonset();
  });
  $( "#check2" ).click(function() {
      $( "#text2" ).toggle();
  });$( "#check3" ).click(function() {
      $( "#text3" ).toggle();
  });

  </script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

**Update
Code does work correctly, however whe I use it in Sharepoint (a content editor webpart) it has an issue where you can click anywhere on the button other than the bounds of the image I have. 
Any chance anyone would know why this is?

Comment: works fine here http://jsfiddle.net/7kb2dcpr/

Comment: Correct.
Would there be any reson why it would work there and not in a sharepoint content editor?

Comment: do you get any errors? have you checked the console?

Comment: There are no errors appearing.
Have tried with a few new images and have concluded that if you click anywhere other then on the image (the empty space of the button & the text) the button will work, but as soon as I try to click within the bounds of the image it doesn't respond.

Comment: Since the code is ok, the problem must be with Sharepoint.

Comment: can you try enclosing the whole checkbox inside the label?

Comment: Code above shoes it contained in the label. do you mean to remove the break?